# Do the spaces between the teeth of a comb have a name?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to Google, they are called "Umpernaters," but I can't find that word anywhere in dictionaries, so I'm tempted to think it's just a legend.

Is there a real term?

Comment: Spaces between the teeth of a comb are one of those things that are not worthy of a name :P

Comment: “According to Google” is about as vacuous a reference as imaginable.

Comment: @DarkLight, don't let tchrist's remark bother you.  It is easy to imagine references far more vacuous than yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that  *umpernater* (rather than *umpernator*) is a term sometimes used.  The only reputable example that I found is from  *[Wetland Archaeology and Beyond: Theory and Practice](http://books.google.com/books?id=9GXUfYTtbfMC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=umpernater&source=bl&ots=lAKnY1Ncdz&sig=Cv2i9Wfs-OMSNtSThF9aqQr7-VY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=56U_UfqyEcLkrAHarYDICQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=umpernater&f=false)*, by Francesco Menotti:
[image]
Possibly it is a Latin term, rather than a recognized English word.

*[Interstices](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interstice#English)* (“A small opening or space between objects, especially adjacent objects or objects set closely together, as between cords in a rope or components of a multiconductor electrical cable or between atoms in a crystal”), as suggested in previous answer and in comments, is a term with a better chance of being recognized.

Comment: Yes, and Menotti, whose book came out only last year, may in fact have been misled by Google too.

Comment: @MετάEd You could ask him: http://ipna.unibas.ch/personen/menotti/index.html :)

Comment: @coleopterist Okay, I did.

Comment: The person who identified the louse gave the word to Sig. Menotti.

Comment: @MετάEd, would that be Karin Wolf-Schwenninger, or did someone else identify it?

Comment: I assume the relevant citation is “Brem et al., 1999”. Which is, I believe, “Neues aus Tasgetium”, Brem H., Steiner D., Kesselring R., *Archäologie der Schweiz*, 1999, vol. 22, no. 3, pp. 123–134. So one of those three authors or an assistant.

Answer (score 2):

What about "interstices," meaning small, narrow, intervening spaces? Of course, this word isn't specific to combs, but it seems to fit.

I'm not finding "umpernators," either. Could you provide the link to the source for this word?

Comment: I think *umpernators* is a complete red herring. Here are a few ["interstices of the comb"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22interstices+of+the+comb%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to back up your suggestion, which is what I'd call them.

Answer (score 1):

The word *redd* means clearing a space or putting in order by separating. Sometimes, according to the OED, combs were referred to as *redding-combs*.

I personally would call the space between the teeth of a comb a *rut*. It's the furrow or gap left between the hard material.