# Are there single words that are defined as "to remain to examine what others passed up"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was beach combing the other day and I wanted to know a word for

"to remain to examine what others have passed up."

This happens in beach combing when you are following your fellow companion and are moving slower, searching for what they might have missed.

Comment: [Scavenger, scrounger, forager](http://thesaurus.com/browse/scavenger?s=ts). [Trash collector](http://thesaurus.com/browse/garbage+man?s=t).

Comment: You could say that you were [umpernating](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107051/do-the-spaces-between-the-teeth-of-a-comb-have-a-name)—maintaining a gap between two members of a comb.

Comment: The verb form of tchrist's words (all good for your meaning): scavange, scrounge, forage.  And my favorite: "garbage pick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word [glean](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glean) comes to mind.

> to gather grain or other produce left by reapers,
>    to pick over in search of relevant material (gleaning old files for information).

Comment: I'd like it more if it the second definition included "what others passed up". I think that 'glean' is the most any single English word can do to cover it.

Comment: I agree with Peter Shor.  Glean is an appropriate word.  The concept of gleaning, as applied to gatherers of grain, is at least as old as the Old Testament commandment, "Nor shall you glean your vineyard, nor shall you gather the fallen fruit of your vineyard; you shall leave them for the needy and for the stranger. I am the LORD your God" (Leviticus 19:10 NAS).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from beachcomber there is garbologist, as nouns, and fossick is the best I can think of as a verb. A forensic pathologist or an archaeologist examine what has been left behind or passed through or thrown up, down or away. Excavation, examination and scrutiny all have aspects (and verbs).

But in terms of what others have left behind/passed up in terms of other scavengers, rather than the original leavers/owners, the best I can come up with is reexamine, rescrutinize or refilter, or repass - often we make multiple filtering passes